# object instance not set to reference

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I can't find a basic error and would need some help finding it. Error comes when in my form load I am trying to display information in my textbox from my database.

- I use the connection everywhere else so it's not the problem
- I tried another Select statement with another table, still the same error.

what am I missing?

> error is Object instance not set to reference

*I know that password shouldnt be stored in a table, I am just playing around*

```
  clsDataSource.mycon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\carole\Desktop\CollegeLasalleFall2016\ProgrammationEvenementielle\RealEstate\RealEstate.mdb");
        clsDataSource.mycon.Open();
         DataSet myset = new DataSet();
        int current = 0;

       OleDbCommand mycmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT UserID, email, pwd, FirstName, LastName, BoolAgent, BoolAdmin FROM Users WHERE (BoolAgent = 1)", clsDataSource.mycon);
        OleDbDataAdapter myadapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(mycmd);
        myadapt.Fill(myset, "AllAgents");

      DataTable tbUser = myset.Tables["Users"];


 //fill the textbox
        txtFirstName.Text = tbUser.Rows[current]["FirstName"].ToString();
```

Comment: Most probably `tbUser` be null

Comment: I tried without tbuser so to do myset.table["Users"].Rows[current]["FirstName"].ToString(); and its still the same problem. I tried my select with another table, still the same problem. So I don't think the problem comes from the table but another small thing in the code...

Comment: Please see the marked duplicate for extensive advice on diagnosing and fixing code that throws `NullReferenceException`. If after following that advice, you are still unable to solve your problem, post a new question that includes **a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem** and a clear but concise explanation of what you've done so far to diagnose the problem and what _specifically_ you are still having trouble with. See also [ask] for additional advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.